# How to enable the display of 1080p HD videos on Vimeo instead of the 720p default

Tags: video, vimeo

I often upload videos to Vimeo.

Last time I uploaded a video on Vimeo, I noticed that there was an option to display my videos in 1080p instead of 720p. 
Who wouldn't want that, right?

[image: option suggestion to display videos in 1080p instead of default 720p]

So I clicked on the "there's an option for that" link that we can see above.

I was then taken to a FAQ page, where the explanation to achieve a 1080p presentation are quite difficult to grasp:

[image: Vimeo's FAQ entry to display a video in 1080p instead of 720p]

It reads "*you’ll need to upgrade your video under the “Video File” tab of your Video Settings page.*"

Only... well, the "video file" tab of the video's settings page is where I just was:

[image]

And I really don't see any option to do that there!

Comment: Do you have any ad-blocker on?

Comment: I have turned ad blockers on and off with the same results. The options on the Video File tab remain the same.

Comment: Are you on basic or PRO? Basic are limited to 720 https://vimeo.com/help/faq/watching-videos/playback-issues#why-cant-i-upgrade-my-video-to-1080p-anymore

Comment: Thanks Malaise! I should have read that FAQ better - although it's strange that they would have asked me to turn on this option, or maybe it was just a badly written commercial message. Please make your comment an answer so I can upvote you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option to upgrade a video to 1080p is there, but available only to Plus and PRO members:

> [Why can’t I upgrade my video to 1080p anymore?](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/watching-videos/playback-issues#why-cant-i-upgrade-my-video-to-1080p-anymore)
>
> Good news: Plus and PRO members no longer need to manually upgrade their videos to 1080p. If you’ve uploaded a 1080p source file, we’ll automatically make both a 720p and 1080p version. (Please note that Basic members are limited to 720p video at this time.)

The option should appear once/if you upgrade your account to Plus or PRO level.

Answer (score 2):

As Basic Vimeo user I dropped all thoughts of upgrading to a pay account upon learning that 1080p uploaded films will revert to 720p once you go back to the free account. This means paying for eternity if you want to maintain quality.

More or less by accident I discovered that **replacing** a video file that I sent up originally as a 720p file can be **replaced** by a 1080p file without even drawing extra for the bigger file from the weekly limit. The video then is viewable in 1080p!

Can't tell if this is a temporary opening or an option that will disappear again. There are lot of changes being made by Vimeo which I can't find much info about, like the "Auto" setting, making me crazy sometimes with the erratic jumps between image qualities.

But right now I work with **replacing** files until I'm blue in my face! Here is an example, I usually do still image shows. https://vimeo.com/155286582

Comment: This sounds great! I'll try it when I get home